# Learning JS - Can't put the result of a counter to work in a field

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

I'm really new at this so forgive my ignorance.

I am trying to improve a exercise typing speed code by adding an error counter. I managed to add the new field for the counter on HTML and css alright. However I just didn't manage to place the result of the error counter in this newly created field. I have made a console.log of the counter and it works alright. Any help is appreciated.
Regards.

I tried all sort of variations using innerHTML and different fields without success.

```
<!--HTML-->
<section class="error-counter-area">
   <h5 id="ectitle">ERROR COUNTER</h5>
   <div class="error-counter">0000</div>
</section>


//JS
const theErrorCounter = document.querySelector(".error-counter");

//var errorCounter = 0000; //Initial 4 digits format for errorCounter, but I don't know how to make it work in the same time with the counter inside the function...

function errorCounterRun() {
   var i = 0;
   errorCounter = i++;
   theErrorCounter.innerHTML = errorCounter;
   console.log(errorCounter); // This works fine, it counts except that it is counting the backspace too, but that is another problem...
}
```

The counter should be shown in the errorCounter H5 field and not only in the console.log.

Comment: `console.log(errorCounter)`, please check what you really used.

Comment: You keep reinitializing the (useless) `i` variable to zero. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5aystLng/

Comment: Regarding the `0000`: a number doesn’t have a format, it’s just a value, so `0000` is the exact same value as `0`. Only when you print a number as a string does the format become relevant. By default, numbers are stringified as base-10 decimal without leading zeros. If you want leading zeros, you need to pad the string.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: hi, the console.log is `errorCounter` the i was a comment mistake. I don't understand how the leading zeros will work, anyhow all I get is a zero, it not even count to 9. In the other hand the `console.log` works fine... Thank you for the suggestions, I guess the issue is something else missing.